# How to properly thread a twitter bot in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, twitter

I am using python and tweepy to create a program that does two things on Twitter :

1. Tweet something at 15 minutes interval
2. Scrape mentions every 30 seconds and answer some of them

What I have ended up with is a program that creates three threads : two daemon threads, one for each tasks, that run in the background, and one "main" thread that does basically nothing except wait for TERM signals to cancel the other two and shut down the program.
Here's what it looks like :

```
def run(self):
    while self.running:
        self.running= not self.handler.receivedTermSignal
        time.sleep(1)

    self.tweet.cancel()
    self.mentions.cancel()
```

It seems to be working as intended but it feels like a dirty hack. Isn't there a better way to handle that kind of things ?

Comment: The thread can't cancel from outside. Maybe you can try asyncio in Py3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `asyncio` in Python 3.

```
import signal
import asyncio
from time import strftime

async def tweet():
    while 1:
        print(strftime('[%H:%M:%S]'), "tweet something")
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(15 * 60)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            break

async def mentions():
    while 1:
        print(strftime('[%H:%M:%S]'), "scrape mentions and answer some of them")
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(30)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            break

def shutdown():
    print(strftime('[%H:%M:%S]'), "shutdown")
    for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
        task.cancel()

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)

    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(tweet()), asyncio.ensure_future(mentions())]

    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```